# How to show places like "national parks" using google maps sdk in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm using xcode 6.4, Swift and iOS8. My goal is to show a map using the google maps (and places?) sdk. This map should contain all results google delivers when i search for "national park" on google maps.

What I already did is the following:

1. Create an API Key for iOS at google (places and maps sdk)
2. Show the map and the users current position

Now I'm struggling in showing the parks when the user opens the map. I already dived around in googles sdk documentation, and came to the conclusion that I'll need the Places SDK for that. But now I'm a bit lost, all I find are scenarios in which the user either has to choose between different "place types" or the app is calling information for one particular place, knowing its id.

Comment: I'm receiving downvotes for this - is my question not clear enough? Or did I violate some rules? I just want to understand it to make it better next time I ask something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you have the key and every thing you can get places by calling the map api like this. the parameters (format strings are self explanatory) you have to tell the center location by giving `latitude` `longitude` (you can get it from users location if you want to show surrounding places). `distance` is the area for which you want to query for places. `types` this mention types of places so it canbe parks, restaurants etc.

When you have run the query you will get a list of places with details and the you have to draw using map annotations

```
var googleURLString NSString(format:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=%@&types=%@&sensor=true&key=%@",latitude, longitute, distance, type, apiKey ) as String

let googleURL = NSURL(string: googleURLString)

let locationData = NSData(contentsOfURL: googleURL!, options: nil, error: nil)

let dataToUse = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(locationData, options:   NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error:&error) as NSDictionary

let locations = dataToUse["results"]
```